# undefined references in gcc link with udev on elux 5

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, udev

I am trying to link some propetary code on eLux 5 (works on eLux 4) a special Linux distribution.
The command line is very long and contains: -ludev -lpenDriverApi (both dynamic libraries, penDriverApi ist the propetary code which depends on udev).
Now the linker tolds me that various references are undefined from udev like 'udev_monitor_unref'. With "nm" I verified that these references are available within the udev shared object - so this error messages are really strange to me.
Because I also tried various verbose/debug settings for the linker I am now at a point without having a clou how to find out what went wrong during linking of my cmake project.

Hopefully this picture is readable, because the damned vmware would allow copy/paste which is enabled (maybe the elux config is bad).

[image: Linker command and error messages]

udev Version on eLux 4 is 0.6.1
udev Version in eLux 5 is 1.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem was, that the third party shared library libpenDriverApi.so required recompilation with a libudev.so.1 as well as a change to the linker, so that ldd -r also shows the dependency to libudev.

Answer (score 0):

In the linkage sequence any object file or library that requires symbol
definitions must appear before the library that provides the definitions,
or undefined reference errors will ensure. This is because the
linker by default will search a library only to find definitions of
symbols that it has observed are referenced, but not defined, in earlier
files.

So if `libpenDriverApi` depends on `libudev` then you have to link in the order:

```
-lpenDriverApi -ludev
```

Comment: The order has been done by cmake, but I also have tried the linker command myself on the command line, so I also tried to change the order of the -l's without changing the result :(

Comment: @user3021395 In that case you'll need to post at least the entire failing linkage command and the errors that follow from it. Add them to the body of your question. To get `make` to print what it's actually doing do `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: I wish that would be possible but this damned vmware machine wouldn't let be (while guest isolation copy/paste is enabled). Maybe a screenshot would work.

Comment: @user3021395 `make VERBOSE=1 1>buildlog.txt 2>&1` then copy the buildlog.txt out of the VM.

Comment: Added screenshot. Question: could it be that the udev version from elux  is so old, that the properetary library must be compiled/linked against the never udev version from elux 5? I have verified all changes of the udev versions without finding something related to the references mentioned in the errors - so everything should be ok from my point of view.

Comment: Also its strange that ldd on the libpenDriveApi would not shown an dependency for udev shared lib ....

Comment: @digipenKH It may be too old, depending on your version of g++, There was an ABI break at GCC 5.1 that would break compatibility with libraries built with older versions.

Comment: On eLux 5 gcc 4.8.1 is used, so this could not be the reason.

Comment: On eLux 4 it is a gcc 4.4.3

Comment: Maybe it is important that eLux 4 is based on gentoo while elux 5 is based on ubuntu?

Comment: Hmm now I found that on eLux 4 there is not only a libudev.so, but also a libudev.a in the library path while on eLux 5 there is only the shared object and no static one....